# How to send uri segment value from view to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri

I have a view where I get uri segment, display the image and edit it's information based on the value I get.

```
$filename = $this->uri->segment(3);
```

In the controller I have to modify a field in the database where $filename matches, and add another few rows using the same $filename. This happens in a separate function in the controller, because I'm submitting other data with a form.

How do I send this value to the controller, or how do I get it again from the controller?

Comment: Why can't you get it in the controller the same way you get it in the view?

Comment: Because the URL is different then. URL in the view is something like http://website.com/controller/function1/imageID, and the URL after the submit is http://website.com/controller/function2

Comment: So why not submit to example.com/controller/function2/imageID ?

Comment: I really didn't think of that >_<. Or maybe I thought it won't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You need put segment in a variable in controller :

```
class Site extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('uri');
        $this->_data['thirdSegment'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->load->view("site/site_view", $this->_data);
    }
}
```

References in CodeIgniter: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

*Good Lucky.*

Answer (score 0):

Include a hidden field in the form `<input type="hidden" name="filename" value="<?=$filename?>">` and submit then. Hope it helps.